# Return value of triggered event into triggering box in Excel VB Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 userforms, Userform_1 contains many TextBoxes (TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, .....) & in Userform_2 I have 1 TextBox where user can enter value. Now I need to pass the User entered value in Userform_2 to be shown/stored in its respective triggering TextBox event in Userform_1. So when User want to pass in TextBox3 (Userform_1) then he/she will just use double_click trigger (activate Userform_2) & pass value which should be stored in TextBox3 only.

I tried this:

In Userform_1

```
Private Sub TextBox3_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   On Error Resume Next
   UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

In Userform_2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    If UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = "" Then UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ComboBox1.Value
    If UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = "" Then UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = ComboBox1.Value
    If UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = "" Then UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = ComboBox1.Value
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Problem is that it will display entered value in any TextBox which is empty & not specifically in TextBox3. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: Please give examples of what you have, what you're trying to do, and the related code that you have so far.

Comment: Never ever use `On Error Resume Next` without error handling. This hides error messages but the errors still occur you just cannot see them.

Comment: PEH.. Yes while writing code I never uses it but I kept it for final entry to avoid abrupt crash/closing of application, if some unidentified error occurs. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ADJ...
Your concept is good but it doesn't quite fulfill the requirement, just hiding the Userform doesn't remove/clear the entered value for next entry & reopening it again shows last entered value. I can write a code to blank it but then I have too many textboxes.
I used your concept of only calling required Userform from a specific TextBox...

Wrote below code, fits my requirement:

UserForm_1:
created hidden TextBox1 in UserForm_2 for identifier

```
UserForm2.TextBox1.Value = "<random identifier value>"
```

UserForm_2:

```
If TextBox1.Value = "<random identifier value>" Then
    UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = "<User Input>"
End If
```

So this way I get to assign & call only identified TextBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly what you have asked it to do (not what you want it to do). Based on your description above, I offer the following (not tested).

In Userform_1

```
Private Sub TextBox3_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   UserForm2.Show
   TextBox3.Value = UserForm2.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

In Userform_2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide  
    'Note not unloading, this means that the userform is still in memory and you can access the values after it is hidden.
    ' Also, hiding the form will return control back to the UserForm1 for further processing.
End Sub
```

And avoid using `On Error`, especially `On Error Resume Next`, all you are doing is hiding the bugs, not dealing with them. If you can anticipate that your code is going to cause an error, deal with it before that piece of code.